# Unity pixel art distorted sprites

Tags: unity, pixel-art

I have a problem rendering my pixel art sprites properly in Unity. 
So far I have one character in a sprite-sheet I made, with frames of size 64x64. The actual sprite is roughly 32x32 but I left room for movement in animations.
I import the sheet following pixel perfection procedures I found on the internet using these settings:

[image: import settings]

As for the orthographic camera I set its size using this formula:

orthoCameraSize = screenHeight / (2 * 32)

If I zoom on the sprite in scene it looks fine but when in game it gets rendered quite poorly (in game / in scene pics below):

[image]

What could be the source of the problem? I applied every good practice advice I could find on the web...
Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: An image of the "poor" rendering would help potential answerers helping you out.

Comment: I can double check, but one of my resources said to set the pixels per unit to 100 for 2D images and the camera size to screen height / 2.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/83437/48257

Comment: @ps2goat the answer you link doesn't suggest using screen height / 2, and in fact that will be a poor choice for many purposes. It makes each Unity game unit 1 pixel in size, which is much finer-grained than the physics system is optimized for, and is completely unsuitable to a pixels per unit setting of 100 (a 100 pixel sprite would get crunched down to 1 on-screen pixel - almost certainly not what the game creator wants!)

Comment: thanks guys. I added pictures to make it more clear... What are your thoughts..?

Comment: Are you setting `orthoCameraSize = screenHeight / (2 * 32)` automatically from a script or do you calculate the value manually? When it's the first I might know what your mistake could be.

Comment: Nothing seems "poor" in the image you showed. The sprites look the same to me.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Zoom in and look more closely at the headband, the row of pixels above the belt and the top of the left boot. The rows are duplicated.

Comment: Oh I see, a few parts of the sprite seem to be a little stretched. My bad, wasn't expecting a "find five differences" puzzle :P

Comment: @Philipp I set the orthoCameraSize directly in the inspector, no scripting....

Comment: @DMGregory - I followed up with my source.  The answer I linked to was an example of setting 1 unit to 100 pixels.  My original source was a unity book (beginner's guide), so I don't know if it will actually fix the issue.  He said to use 100 pixels per unit in the Pixels-to-Unit ratio when importing the sprites, then set the camera height to `screensize / 2 / 100`. pages 100-102 if you look inside the book: https://www.amazon.com/Unity-Action-Multiplatform-Game-Development/dp/161729232X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1468615723&sr=1-1&keywords=unity

Comment: I answered a [similar question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35829604/3064164) - this can be caused when you have a non-integer number of screen pixels for each source texel in the sprite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes scaling pixel art different than other images?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131445/what-makes-scaling-pixel-art-different-than-other-images). My bet is that the manually-calculated orthoCameraSize was not chosen correctly for the size of the game window, resulting in a non-integer scaling factor being applied.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your formula for the ortho size to 
Camera Size = x / ((( x / y ) * 2 ) * s )

Where: 
x = Screen Width (px) 
y = Screen Height (px) 
s = Desired Height of Photoshop Square (px)

Comment: I'll have to give this formula a try. I've been doing the screenHeight/2*ppu one I was advised once. Incidentally, how does your formula account for ppu (pixels per unit)?

Comment: The result from this formula is the same as screenHeight/2*ppu. It's just a slightly more complicated one...

Answer (score 1):

Should be the same problem / answer as this:

[How do I move the camera in full pixel intervals?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129112/how-do-i-move-the-camera-in-full-pixel-intervals/129282#129282)

Basically to fix this issue:

1. Your sprites-pixel in Unity-Units should be reasonable. ( For example: If your sprite has a width of 10, it should be as wide as "10 unity-units"  for example. Or 100. or 1. or 0.1f. But not 1.5234f)
2. Your sprites should only move in full-pixel-steps if (1.) is not possible.
3. Your Camera should also only move in a full pixel- steps if (1.) is not possible
4. Your Resolution should be in full numbers (x = 50.5f is wrong)
5. Your Resolution should have even numbers
6. Your Camera-Y-Rotation and Camera-X-Rotation should be 0
7. Your Camera-Projection should be Orthographic
8. Your "Size" should be like this : https://indiehoodgames.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/pixel-perfect-calculator-for-orthographic-camera-unity3d/

Answer (score 1):

check the scale slider in game window it must be x1 for better quality

Comment: I think this is a valid answer, but it's a little on the short side and got auto-flagged by our system as a result. I recommend editing your answer to add more details - maybe a link to the documentation about this feature, a screenshot of where to find it & what it looks like in the editor, or an explanation of why scaling using this slider affects visual quality.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off anti-aliasing completely in the project settings.

Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality

[image]

Here, disable Anti Aliasing, and Anisotropic Textures.

Comment: thanks Jon. This solution made it a little worse though...

Comment: haha. ok can you provide more details on this particular gameobject?  Do you have a 1:1 scale value?  Do you have an attached animator?  Is the animator affecting the scale of the sprite?  Is the actual sprite 32pixels wide?  Try setting the camera orthoSize to an integer value.

Comment: The scale is 1.1, it has an animator which changes the sprite without stretching it, the sprite is actually 32x32. I noticed that if I set the scale to 1 it gets rendered much better, but I have to make it bigger somehow in order to match other sprites size... How can I deal with that...?

Comment: You can check out something like this:  https://github.com/RyanNielson/PixelCamera2D  -- OR alternatively, another approaches:  http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/

Answer (score -3):

Try setting the compression to rgba 24bit (override default) and filter mode to point.

Comment: You can see in the question itself that the texture has already been imported uncompressed, with point filtering - so this isn't telling the user anything they haven't already done. Plus, the artifacts shown don't look like compression or bilinear interpolation, so it's unclear how this answer is intended to solve the problem.