# How to use Unity to slice sprite

Tags: unity, spritesheet

The polygon slice function of TexturePacker Pro is very nice, it suit the size of the sprite. However my TexturePacker Pro trial had finished, and by using Unity Sprite Editor will make my sliced sprite tremble, I don't know why.

How can I use Unity Sprite Editor to slice my sprites correctly?

Comment: Can you describe what it looks like when your sliced sprite "trembles" or even better, record a video or gif so we can see the effect ourselves? It might not be the slicing/packing that's causing it. [Rippling sprite artifacts can occur due to scale mismatches](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129112/how-do-i-move-the-camera-in-full-pixel-intervals/129363#129363), so there may be other routes to solving your problem.

Comment: i have see that each sprite of your character in sprite sheet is shaped square , why don't you just use square instead of polygon ?

Comment: @DMGregory but I can't attach video or gif file

Comment: @user6668201 I'm using Unity sprite editor, setting - sprite mode: multiple and format: true color, using grid by cell size make it into square size and slice it

Comment: That's odd — even when you click the "edit" button on your question? I didn't think there was a rep threshold for gifs but I could be mistaken. Instead, you can upload to Giphy or YouTube and edit your question to include the link to the gif/video respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are seeing trembling in your sprite animations the problem is the pivot point on the sprite sheet. In Unity, the pivot point looks like a blue circle on each sliced sprite in the editor (see screenshot). The pivot point acts as the point of rotation and also the starting point for where the sprite will be rendered in the scene. To fix the problem click the pivot point and on each sliced sprite and drag it to a position that you know will stay constant, like an eyeball or a foot.[image]

Comment: Ok ... I try your method and see whether it function or not ... thanks ^^