# 2D Top Down Follow Camera Stuttering

Tags: unity, 2d, camera

I am making a top down pixel art game and am using a simple follow script for my camera.

```
void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, target.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
```

However i get this weird stuttering effect while moving around:
https://gfycat.com/tintedlightheartedcrayfish

Any way to smooth out the camera movement?

Comment: This doesn't look like stuttering to me — the movement is smooth, not stop-and-start. I'd describe this as a shimmering in your background sprites. This can occur if you're using Nearest Neighbour / Point filtering for crisp pixels, but you're displaying them at a screen size that's not quite an integer multiple of their source size. [I have some past answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829604/3064164) [showing this in action](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/157021/39518), which may be of some help to you.

Comment: Why don't use cinemachine and get rid of all camera coding problems forever.

Comment: @DMGregory I am using PixelPerfect Camera and have it set to 16 Pixels per Unit so its 1:1 to the tilesize.

Comment: @Ivan I get artifact lines in between tiles when moving using Cinemachine, which I don't get when using Pixel Perfect. that's why I've chosen it.
Tried to mess around with Cinemachine to get rid of those artifacts but to no avail.

Comment: @DMGregory i sorta fixed it, since i was using Pixel Snapping setting in Pixel Perfect Camera that caused the shimmering, however it is still there when moving diagonally

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps to create a minimal complete verifiable example of this problem in a new, empty project? This can let us test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for your case.

Comment: @DMGregory it has been fixed however i get artifact lines now since i added LWRP to my project. I am using a 2D Renderer for it and i dont understand the message Pixel Perfect is telling me:

Pixel Perfect Camera in the 2D Pixel Perfect package isnt compatible with Scriptable Render Pipeline. If you are using the LWRP, you can swap this for the Pixel Perfect Camera component that ships with LWRP.

what does this mean? i already have the Pixel Perfect Camera component on my Main Camera.

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to ask that.