# Artifacts on top of platform sprite only when moving

Tags: unity, sprites, movement

I made a floating platform in Unity which has a propeller movement animation. I attached a script I wrote to the game object that adds slight vertical and horizontal movement using the game object `transform.position`. This is creating some weird artifacts at the top of the sprite, but only when the movement code is active. When I don't move the platform and just leave it still to animate there are no artifacts.

**Gameplay:**

[image: gif of gameplay]

**Sprite Import Settings:**

[image: sprite import settings]

**Sprite Renderer:**

[image: sprite renderer settings]

**Camera Settings:**

[image: camera settings]

Resolution:

[image: resolution settings]

Comment: Looks like you're drawing the sprite at a scale that's [not quite an integer ratio of screen pixels to sprite texels](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129363/39518). So in motion, sometimes your outline spans more pixels vertically, causing it to be drawn thicker for a frame. Can you show us how you've set up the sprite texture, its import settings, its renderer, the camera, and your display window size?

Comment: @DMGregory Added! Let me know if I missed anything. One thing I did leave out is that I'm scaling the platform by 2 in the X and Y.

Comment: Still missing the transform on your sprite renderer, and the dimensions of your window.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm not sure what you mean by window. Size of the game view? I updated the sprite renderer pic to include the transform.

Comment: Yep. To get a perfect integer ratio of screen pixels to sprite texels, we need to know the exact size your game will be displayed on screen.

Comment: @DMGregory added resolution from game settings, not sure if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: We literally need the number of pixels on your game view from top to bottom. If your game window does not have a defined size, then you will have a much harder time correcting for this kind of artifact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106725/discussion-between-christopher-perry-and-dmgregory).