# Changing Pixels Per Unit

Tags: unity, 2d, pixel

First off, excuse my ignorance. I am just getting started in game dev. and ran into a little issue. So I had these weird rippling-lines going across my screen, and saw in a couple forums that this means I don't have what is called a "pixel perfect" game. To fix this, I am supposed to change the pixels-per-unit of each sprite down to 1. Currently I had it on 32 because that is my sprite size and I am a complete noob.

Now, I change it down to one but it completely destroyed my game. Everything that is generated on my map/grid is sucked into the center in this giant orb of sprites (I procedurally generate my map off a grid of 1/0s). I am guessing there is just a setting or some such thing that I am missing. Any ideas?

Also would be happy with an alternative to remove the rippling lines.

Comment: No, changing pixels per unit to 1 will not fix that. This is a common superstition among Unity devs, and I'd argue changing your PPU to 1 can actually be harmful. What you need is to ensure your camera size is chosen so that the number of pixels on your screen/window is an integer multiple of the number of worldspace units your camera sees times your pixels per unit value. [I have a few existing answers on this topic, mostly linked through this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131445/39518) which may help you build some intuition into what's happening here.

Comment: @DMGregory ...or you could just use the [2D pixel perfect package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.pixel-perfect@3.0/manual/index.html).

Comment: Which does what the answers describe, yes.