# Can I use different Tile/Sprite Sizes on the same Tilemap?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, tilemap, tiles

My partner and I are creating a 2D RPG with D&D elements with Unity.

I am very new to Unity and making games in general, apart from 2 games which I created with Java and the rougelike tutorial which I did with Unity. For this university project we have 4 months and my partner has the job creating tiles, sprites, sound and music. I will program the game.

My question is:

Can we create 32x32 tiles and 64x64 sprites in the same tilemap or does everything need to be the same size?

If we can combine them, will a 64x64 sprite on a 32x32 tilemap take 4 tiles, or can we scale it down to one tile?

Comment: Can you clarify what's leading you to want to mix tile sizes this way? [General advice when working with low-resolution/pixel art sprites](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131445/39518) is to [keep the pixel density the same](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141609/39518) for a consistent appearance. There might be a good reason to break this guideline in your game but we'll need to hear about that from you. [We can't tell you what sprite size to use](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140072/39518) - that's a choice you'll need to make for yourself.

Comment: The Main reason we thought to use different Tile/Sprite Sizes is because the background doesnt need as many details as a person/enemy or something like this. Thats why we thought 32x32 for tiles and 64x64 for sprites

Comment: That sounds then like your tilemap is using 100% 32x32 tiles. Your character sprites, which are drawn *over* the tilemap, not embedded in it, can be any size you want. They don't have to conform to the grid, and can walk smoothly from one grid cell to another, overlapping as they go. Did you try a test to see what that looks like? (Say, grabbing some existing sprites at the resolutions you're thinking about for a quick & dirty mock-up) Did you run into any particular problems making this test work? We can help you solve problems, but at present it's not obvious what obstacle you'd face here.

Comment: Sry,  I try to clarify. If I use a 32x32 tilemap, does my 64x64 Sprite of my playable character take 4 tiles?

Comment: The links really help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have both 64x64 tiles and 32x32 tiles.  If you want both of them to take only one square, you will have to adjust the **pixels per unit.**  If you don't know what that is, please comment and I'll help you.